# Werkzeug issue:AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, html, flask, recommendation-engine, werkzeug

I have tried my hand at a recommendation engine. I cant seem to solve this error in the password field; it is taking an integer as an attribute which prohibits usage of count() method.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2551, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2531, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\APP_VERSIONS\RECOMM_SYS_v5\RECOMM_SYS_v5\application\routes.py", line 83, in login
    if user and user.get_password(fpassword): # encrypted password
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\APP_VERSIONS\RECOMM_SYS_v5\RECOMM_SYS_v5\application\models.py", line 21, in get_password
    return check_password_hash(self.Password, Password)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\GitHub\recommender_system\env\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\security.py", line 103, in check_password_hash
    if pwhash.count("$") < 2:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'
```

I cant seem to understand where to start digging.
I have tried some things on `models.py` and `routes.py` but nothing seems to work.
My `models.py`:

```py
from application import db
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

class movies(db.Document):
    Movie_Id        =   db.IntField(unique = True)
    Year            =   db.IntField()
    Name            =   db.StringField(max_length = 255)
    Link            =   db.StringField(max_length = 255)

class users(db.Document):
    Cust_Id     =   db.IntField(unique = True)
    First_Name  =   db.StringField(max_length = 200)
    Last_Name   =   db.StringField(max_length = 200)
    Email       =   db.StringField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
    Password    =   db.StringField( )

    def print_password(self, Password):
        print(generate_password_hash(Password))
    
    def get_password(self, Password):
        return check_password_hash(self.Password, Password)
```

and `routes.py`:

```py
from application import app, db
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash, session
from application.models import movies, users
from application.forms import LoginForm

ratings_ = [{'Movie_Id': 6552,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Rating': 1.0,
  'Name': "Charlie's Angels"},
 {'Movie_Id': 8099,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Rating': 1.0,
  'Name': 'Reign of Fire'},
 {'Movie_Id': 9340, 'Cust_Id': 1132304, 'Rating': 4.0, 'Name': 'Pearl Harbor'},
 {'Movie_Id': 12672, 'Cust_Id': 1132304, 'Rating': 4.0, 'Name': 'John Q'},
 {'Movie_Id': 16272,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Rating': 2.0,
  'Name': 'Crouching Tiger'},
 {'Movie_Id': 17157,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Rating': 3.0,
  'Name': 'Saving Private Ryan'}]

preds_ = [{'Movie_Id': 11283,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Predicted_Rating': 3.2,
  'Name': 'Forrest Gump'},
 {'Movie_Id': 17085,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Predicted_Rating': 3.0,
  'Name': '24: Season 2'},
 {'Movie_Id': 13468,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Predicted_Rating': 3.0,
  'Name': 'Law & Order: Season 3'},
 {'Movie_Id': 7234,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Predicted_Rating': 3.0,
  'Name': 'Men of Honor'},
 {'Movie_Id': 15861,
  'Cust_Id': 1132304,
  'Predicted_Rating': 2.9,
  'Name': 'CSI: Season 2'}]

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", navindex=True)

@app.route("/catalog")
def catalog():
    moviecat_ = movies.objects.all()
    return render_template("catalog.html", navcatalog=True, moviecat=moviecat_)

@app.route("/reviews")
def reviews():
    if not session.get('Cust_Id'):
        flash(f"Please login to access reviews", "danger")
        return redirect(url_for('login')) # If not logged in, redirect user to login page
    return render_template("reviews.html", navreviews=True, ratings=ratings_)

@app.route("/recommend")
def recommend():
    if not session.get('Cust_Id'):
        flash(f"Please login to access recommendations", "danger")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))  # If not logged in, redirect user to login page
    return render_template("recommend.html", navrecommend=True, predictions=preds_)

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if session.get('Cust_Id'):
        return redirect(url_for('index'))  # If already logged in, redirect user to home page
    
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Get form data
        femail = request.form.get("email")
        fpassword = request.form.get("password")
        # Compare data against db
        #user = users.objects(Email = femail, Password = fpassword).first() # clear password
        user = users.objects(Email = femail).first()
        #user.print_password(fpassword)
        if user and user.get_password(fpassword): # encrypted password
            flash(f"Welcome back, {user.First_Name}", "success")
            session['Cust_Id'] = user.Cust_Id
            session['First_Name'] = user.First_Name
            session['Last_Name'] = user.Last_Name
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            flash("Sorry, login failed", "danger")            
    return render_template("login.html", form=form, navlogin=True)

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session['Cust_Id'] = False
    session.pop('First_Name', None)
    session.pop('Last_Name', None)
    return redirect("/")
```

Comment: I have no idea what `pwhash` is, but the error message is pretty clear.  It's an integer, and you're expecting it to be a string.